# Aerospike space occupying

Tags: aerospike

Initially, I have 2 sets(tables) each contains 45gb of data which is total 90gb of data in 1 namespace(database), So I decided to remove 1 set to free up the ram size, after deletion of 1 set, again it shows 90gb, ram size changed nothing. Without a restart of aerospike server, Is there a way to flush the deleted data to free up my ram ??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: How did you delete the set and how are you checking for the RAM usage?

Comment: Also how many objects are in one of these sets?

Comment: Which version of Aerospike are you using?

Comment: free -g command shows ram usage

To delete set - "java -jar delete-set-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -h host -p 3000 -n test -s demo" @Meher

Comment: what is the configuration of namespace test?

Comment: 203626188 objects @kporter

Comment: version 3.12.1.1 @RonenBotzer

Comment: `namespace test {
 replication-factor 2
 memory-size 180G
 default-ttl 0 # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.
 
 storage-engine device {
  device /dev/sdb2
  scheduler-mode noop
  write-block-size 1024K
  data-in-memory true
 }
}`
configuration of namespace test @pgupta

Comment: free -g command shows ram usage -> Well, Linux wouldn't necessarily report memory used as you would expect.  You could also check detail memory usage from the logs in recent Server versions to see if there was any potential fragmentation. Look for the string 'heap' in logs. Refer to https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/serverlogmessages/index.html for details on how to read log lines as such: `system-memory: free-kbytes 305769484 free-pct 57 heap-kbytes (135693715,211404072,233721856) heap-efficiency-pct 58.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Aerospike CE 3.12](https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.12.0) on up you should be using the [truncate](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info#truncate) command to [truncate the data](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/sets/index.html#truncating-a-set-in-a-namespace) in a namespace, or a set of a namespace.

The `aerospike/delete-set` repo is an ancient workaround (hasn't been updated in 2 years). In the Java client simply use the [`AerospikeClient.truncate()`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.html#truncate(com.aerospike.client.policy.InfoPolicy,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Calendar)) command.

Comment: Agreed, truncate is a **much** better solution; however, the delete-set tool should have still freed memory.

Comment: This is true. It's quite mysterious why it wouldn't work. That said, the tool needs to be modified to use the truncate method with the right server version.

Comment: I used aql to truncate with storage-engine-device and data-in-memory true - I cannot reproduce the reported problem. memory is freed.

Comment: "java -jar delete-set-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -h host -p 3000 -n test -s demo" is this command truncate the data or delete the data ??

Comment: That command runs a scan operations and issues a delete for each record in a set. The truncate command does not issue individual delete operations but instead creates a background job that remove everything before a user specified time-stamp.